# Sumar valores de columnas que se van agregando en un table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

```
$(document).on("click", ".addCardShop", function () {
row = $(this).closest("tr"); //devuelve el antepasado
id = parseInt(row.find("td:eq(0)").text()); //busca un descendiente
var nomProd = row.find("td:eq(1)").text();
var descriptionProd = row.find("td:eq(2)").text();
var cantProd = $("#cantAdd_" + id).val();
var costo = row.find("td:eq(4)").text();
var total = cantProd * costo;

if (cantProd == "") {
  $.toast({
    heading: "Warning",
    text: "Ingrese la cantidad!",
    showHideTransition: "plain",
    position: "top-right",
    icon: "warning",
  });
  return;
}
var contentTable = `
              <tr>
              
              <td>${id}</td>
              <td>${nomProd}</td>
              <td>${descriptionProd}</td>
              <td>${cantProd}</td>
              <td>${costo}</td>
              <td class='fw-bold total' id = 'subtotal${id}'>${total}</td>
              <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger deleteCardShop"><i class="fa-solid fa-x"></i></button></td>
              </tr>`;


$("#tbody").append(contentTable);
suma_total(id);
});
```

Resulta que estoy haciendo una compra donde agrego un producto y la cantidad que quiero, entonces estos al darle click a un boton 'agregar' aparecen en una fila de un table(los datos respectivamente) y asi sucesivamente cuando agrego productos a la compra, ahora bien, mi problema es que no puedo obtener la suma total de todos los X productos que yo agregue, tengo un codigo pero este lo que me arroja es el numero de filas que inserte como tal, pero cuando agrego un producto este se suma por si mismo dado el numero de filas, cuando lo que deberia hacer es sumarse al valor anterior, adjunto codigo que uso.

```
function suma_total(id) {

var cont_fila = ($('#tableShop tbody').find('tr').length); 

var total_general = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= cont_fila; i++) {
    var subtotal = $('#subtotal'+id).text();
    total_general += Number(subtotal);

}
$("#neto").html((total_general).toFixed(2));

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Explico la imagen, el ultimo producto que ingrese fue el producto D cuyo valor ese de 10 al multiplicarse por la cant de 3 que le asigno deberia ser 30 y sumado mas los anteriores deberia dar un total de 85, pero que paso, bien lo que paso es que al ser 3 filas, lo que hizo fue hacer la multiplicacion es decir 3*10 =30 , pero como son 3 filas ya insertadas hizo esto 30+30+30=90 y por eso el total se puso como 90 en lugar de 85, agradeceria si me pueden ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo haria de este modo, usando clases. Realiza estos cambios:

Donde pones esto:

```javascript
<td class='fw-bold total' id = 'subtotal${id}'>${total}</td>
```

por esto:

```javascript
<td class='subtotal fw-bold total'>${total}</td>
```

pues el **id** no lo vamos a necesitar más, sino que nos recorreremos todos los elementos con la clase `subtotal` de este modo, gracias al método [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) de jquery:

```javascript
function suma_total() {
  let total_general = 0
  $(".subtotal").each(function( index ) {
    total_general += Number($(this).text());
  })
  $("#neto").html((total_general).toFixed(2));
}
```

Prueba y nos cuentas.

Comment: Perfecto, funciono a la perfeccion. Muchas gracias

Comment: Tengo ahi un boton con una X , y si yo le doy click deberia remover una fila y los valores adaptarse a los que existen , que sugerencia me podrias dar. Ya funciona para removerlos, pero falta que los valores se 'adapten' o 'actualicen' a los ya existentes o 0 en caso de que se remuevan todos. Aunque sabes lo que hice fue meter las misma lineas de codigo, es decir cuando le doy click se elimine la fila, pero haga de nuevo la suma y todo, con el codigo que me ayudaste y sabes va bien, comprobe y si, pero eso seria lo correcto o lo valido?

Comment: SI, en principio le puedes pasar la misma función `suma_total()` para que recalcule las sumas de las columna con la clase **subtotal** cada vez que se actualice, elimine o agrege un nuevo valor, claro

Comment: Disculpa que te moleste, pero sabrias como incrementar el numero de factura al guardar una, es decir que si guardo una con numero de factura 1, el campo de numeor de factura seria 2 para la siguiente factura a guardar

Comment: Las facturas no deben numerarse **antes** de ser emitidas, no debe haber un campo de número de factura a menos que ya exista, y para que exista debe haber un pedido realizado en firme. Y es allí, cuando realizas el pedido y compruebas el pago (o lo demoras porque sera por transferencia o por lo que sea) que entonces generas un número de factura en tu base de datos, no en un input **antes** de emitirla. Por lo tanto, no te hace falta eso que pides, pues repito, el orden debe ser: 1) Preparación del pedido 2) Orden de compra (aqui sí que puedes hacerlo) y 3) Factura (que la sacas de la bd)

Comment: A eso me referia, a la orden de compra. Perdon por explicarme mal

Comment: Al orden de compra le sucede otro tanto. Debe generarse cuando el cliente confirma el pedido y pasa a las opciones de pago. Y entonces guardarse en una base de datos con los elementos que contiene para futuras referencias o modificaciones antes de pagar. Al guardarse se genera ese numero de orden de compra, que deberia ser el ID de la tabla. Si lo tienes todo en un paso en lugar de varios, y el cliente solo debe pagar lo que ve en su carrito directamente, no te preocupes por el, simplemente lo agregas cuando recibas el pago, como la factura.

Comment: Y si lo que te preocupa es el número de carrito entonces éste debe generarse automáticamente cuando cualquier cliente ingresa su primer elemento en su carrito, y del mismo modo que lo harias con una factura o orden de compra, usando su ID de tabla. Por lo tanto estariamos hablando de 3 tablas: carrito, ordenes y facturas.  Si quieres puedes hacerlo en dos, donde carrito=ordenes, pero vamos, el procedimiento es el mismo, el número no se incrementa con javascript, sino que lo recibe de la base de datos al introducir un elemento o varios en la tabla carrito (u ordenes si pasas de la tabla carrito